# Plotting discontinuous graph in Excel - Mac 2008

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2008

have some data that has gaps in it and Im not able to plot it in excel. I know I want to uncheck the "Leave Gaps" item in the Tools / Chart / Options panel. Plenty of googling has showed that that's the answer I want. But, I'm using Excel 2008 for OS X, not for Windows. And I can't seem to find that option anywhere!

Here's my data:

[image: data]

Here's my graph from Excel:

[image: excel graph]

and here's what I want. (Drew this in Photoshop)

[image: desired graph]

How can I do this in Excel 2008 for OS X? Thanks!

Comment: Excel on Mac still around? ;-)

Comment: Well, it was on Mac first, so I don't see why it wouldn't be around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Preferences> Chart

I am not sure 2008 and 2011 are the same but in 2011

[image]

[image]

you must do more than uncheck "Leave Gaps"

Check Interpolated

[image]

Comment: how do you bring up that dialog?

Comment: in 2011 Excel>Preferences> under Authoring Chart. In Windows Excel it is under Preferences and earlier versions Tools>Options so that is why I say Mac 2008 I am not sure, but hopefully it is there

Comment: that was it. I can't believe that this is a user preference, not a per chart preference!

Answer (score 1):

In Excel for Mac 2008: the dialog is in the same place as in 2011 (ie Excel>Preferences>Charts)  but it is greyed out unless there is a chart in your worksheet, AND you have clicked on the chart before going to preferences AND it is a chart type which supports interpolation (basically X-Y scatter).

It was all a lot less demanding in PC versioon